# Geolocation in react native runs continously

Tags: react-native, google-maps, geolocation

I tried to create a simple react native application, and show my position in map, with react-native-maps.

```
const [coordinate, setCoordinate] = useState()

    const getCoordinate = () => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(data => {
        setCoordinate({
          latitude: data.coords.latitude,
          longitude: data.coords.longitude,
        });
      });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      getCoordinate();
    })
```

The code works fine, I got my position, marked with a Marker. My problem is why the getCoordinate function calls itself continuously, and running non-stop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing a second argument to the `useEffect` (which should be an array of dependencies) which is causing it to run on every render.

Since you only want it to run once (essentially on mount), you need to pass an empty array as the second argument to your `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getCoordinate();
}, [])
```